# In PHP, how do I select only items which have a quantity greater than 0?

Tags: php

```
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

do{

 $request="SELECT id, name, type, price FROM `corro`.`food`";

$result=mysql_query($request);

}while(quantity>0)
```

Comment: there is an error in the above block of coding which i cannot figur eout

Comment: one small correction to be made($quantity>0)

Comment: Syntax error on last line: while (quantity > 0) should be replaced by while ($quantity > 0)

Comment: @briosheje i did that but it still does not work

Comment: Not sure what youre doing there tbh. Why dont you add the quantity to each dataset in your table and use the WHERE statement of MySQL?

Comment: @Y U NO WORK how is that performed?

Comment: `$quantity` is never set to 0, so it's an endless loop if `$quantity>0`...

Comment: indeed, as Reeno said, since $quantity is never changed this loop is actually an endless loop. Into the "do", you have to change $quantity according to what you want to do.

Comment: @reeno can  u edit the above code to perform what u suggest?

Comment: @briosheje
i want to select items that have q quantity greater than zero

Comment: Where is the quantity of a product stored?

Comment: @Reeno in a table column quantity

Comment: @user2966446 : then just do that in the query, add WHERE quantity > 0

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19997679/1682509. But I don't know why you need `$quantity=$_POST['quantity']`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I assume it's this:

```
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$request="SELECT id, name, type, price FROM `corro`.`food` WHERE quantity>0";
$result=mysql_query($request);
```

Comment: How's $quantity = $_POST['quantity'] relevant since you are not using it?

Comment: Don't know... As I already noted in the comments

Comment: Please note that mysql_query is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you have a syntax error :

```
while (quantity > 0)
```

should be :

```
while ($quantity > 0)
```

**But** If you execute your code, you'll have an infinite loop if $quantity is actually greater than 0 : this will only execute your query over and over again because you never decrement $quantity.

I'm guessing that you have a quantity column in your table so what you should do is put the condition in your SQL query.
Using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that would give you :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name, type, price FROM food WHERE quantity > ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['quantity']));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

EDIT (following the latest answers)

Note that mysql_* are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
if($quantity>0){
  $request="SELECT id, name, type, price FROM `corro`.`food`";
  $result=mysql_query($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in your `mysql_query`

Please note that `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated, and should not be used. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. The query for mysql would be `SELECT id, name, type, price FROM corro.food WHERE quantity>0`

Comment: $request="SELECT id, name, type, price FROM `corro`.`food` WHERE quantity>0" ;

simply in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is running unlimited times try giving condition to your code as in below demo code

```
  $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
  $quantity_count = 0;
  do{
        $request="SELECT id, name, type, price FROM `corro`.`food`";
        $result=mysql_query($request);
        $quantity_count++;
  }while($quantity>0 && $quantity_count < 10);     //This is demo code
```